# Launch Keyboard Config GUI from terminal

Tags: 12.04, unity, keyboard, lxde

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with the LXDE desktop. I would like to launch the standard keyboard configuration GUI tool but cant seem to find it in my menus. Can anybody let me know whats the name of the command I should input in command line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this article solves your problem:

http://noobish-nix.blogspot.de/2012/06/how-to-add-and-switch-keyboard-layout.html